# How to copy a list in Python into a given destination?

Tags: python

Supposing, I have two lists `src` and `trg` that have their own id:

```
>>> src = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(src)
140442981239240
>>> trg = [6, 6, 6]
>>> id(trg)
140442981239368
```

I want to copy all data from `src` into `trg` keeping their `id`. How can I do it?

I tried this:

```
>>> trg = src[:]
>>> id(trg)
140442981322376
```

But it changed `id` unfortunately.

Also I know there's a way to do it like this:

```
>>> del trg[:]
>>> trg.extend(src)
```

It's done in two lines. I believe there's a more elegant way to do the same. Can somebody help me?

Comment: `trg[:] = src`.

Comment: Thanks. That's the way I'm looking for.